# Copying CDATA between 2 xml files

Tags: php, simplexml

I've been banging my head with that one, but it should be simple!

I'm trying to increment xml1 from values parsed in xml2. Working well for all nodes except  that contains CDATA. I am copying according to this loop:

```
$xml1 = simplexml_load_file("history.kml");
$xml2 = simplexml_load_file("history_compare.kml");

foreach ($xml2->Document->Placemark as $Placemark){
        $new_Placemark = $xml1->Document->addChild('Placemark');
        $new_Placemark->addChild('name', $Placemark->name);
        $new_Placemark->addChild('description', $Placemark->description);
        $xml_history->asXML('xml_result.kml');
         }
```

The `<description>` tag in xml2 contains CDATA.
When trying to copy this tag, the result completely escapes the description tag. Here is the output:

```
<Placemark>
  <name>2016-12-29 10:45:39 AM</name>
  <description/>
</Placemark>
```

I want the `<description>` tag to be copied as a CDATA, exactly the same as it is in source $xml2.

I've seen solutions to ignore CDATA but that is not what I'm looking for here.

Thanks

Comment: Could you create a small pair of sample XML blocks that reproduce the error, so people can test proposed solutions? See this help page about the importance of creating a [mcve].